# Duplicate file x times in command shell

Tags: shell, files, file-copy

I try to duplicate a video file x times from the command line by using a for loop, I've tried it like this, but it does not work:

```
for i in {1..100}; do cp test.ogg echo "test$1.ogg"; done
```

Comment: Isn't your only error the `echo` which should not be there, and the `$1` which should be `$i`?

Comment: if i remove the echo and only use `test$1.ogg` then it says: **test.ogg and test.ogg are the same files**, so it seems like $1 is not recognized?

Comment: @EdwardBlack: Sound like I mis-understood your requirements. That solution is not suitable.

Comment: @JuliePelletier, damn, it happens sometimes to me that i accidentially write `$1` instead of `$i`, it is earlie in the morning, sorry... thank you. I will use `$x` in the future instead of `$i`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Your shell code has two issues:

1. The `echo` should not be there.
2. The variable `$i` ("dollar i") is mistyped as `$1` ("dollar one") in the destination file name.

To make a copy of a file in the same directory as the file itself, use

```
cp thefile thecopy
```

If you use more than two arguments, e.g.

```
cp thefile theotherthing thecopy
```

then it is *assumed* that you'd like to copy `thefile` and `theotherthing` into the *directory* called `thecopy`.

In your case with `cp test.ogg echo "test$1.ogg"`, it specifically looks for a file called `test.ogg` and one named `echo` to copy to the directory `test$1.ogg`.

The `$1` will most likely expand to an empty string.  This is why, when you delete the `echo` from the command, you get "test.ogg and test.ogg are the same files"; the command being executed is essentially

```
cp test.ogg test.ogg
```

This is probably a mistyping.

In the end, you want something like this:

```
for i in {1..100}; do cp test.ogg "test$i.ogg"; done
```

Or, as an alternative

```
i=0
while (( i++ < 100 )); do
  cp test.ogg "test$i.ogg"
done
```

Or, using `tee`:

```
tee test{1..100}.ogg <test.ogg >/dev/null
```

Note: This would most likely work for 100 copies, but for thousands of copies it may generate a "argument list too long" error. In that case, revert to using a loop.

Answer (score 19):

```
for i in {1..100}; do cp test.ogg "test_$i.ogg" ; done
```

Answer (score 16):

Short and precise

```
< test.ogg tee test{1..100}.ogg
```

or even better do

```
tee test{1..100}.ogg < test.ogg >/dev/null
```

see [tee command usage](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/) for more help.

**Update**

as suggested by @Gilles, using `tee` has the defect of not preserving any file metadata. To overcome that issue, you might have to run below command after that:

```
cp --attributes-only --preserve Source Target
```

Comment: This is potentially faster than multiple calls to `cp` (depends on the file size relative to available memory), but has the defect of not preserving any file metadata.

Comment: @Gilles ohh, can we overcome that ?

Comment: You can run `cp --attributes-only` afterwards.

Comment: @Gilles thanks, updated my answer as per your help.

Comment: FWIW none of the other answers used `cp -p` to preserve metadata either.

Comment: What are examples of file metadata that may not be preserved by tee?

Comment: @theonlygusti File permissions, ownership, etc. Basically anything that 'stat' returns.

Answer (score 2):

The folowing command will copy **file.a** 5 times:

```
$ seq 5 | xargs -I AA cp file.a fileAA.a
```

If you prefer dd (not the same as cp!):

```
$ seq 5 | xargs -I AA dd if=file.a of=fileAA.a
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not called variable i  while copying

use below script . As tested it worked fine

```
for i in {1..10}; do cp -rvfp test.ogg test$i.ogg ;done
```

Comment: This is the same as two previous answers and a comment except (1) the question asks about 100, and your answer uses 10, (2) you have unnecessarily added the `-rvf` options to `cp`, and (3) you have failed to quote your variable expansion. (Also note that it’s conventional to have a space between punctuation symbols like `;` and the following word.) The addition of the `-p` option is valuable, but (4a) it’s been addressed already (in comments), and (4b) your answer isn’t helpful if you don’t explain what you’re doing.