# Copy a file a number of times with names that come from a list

Tags: linux, command-line, cp

I have a list of names and I have a binary file.  I want to copy that binary file so that there is one copy for each member of the list.  The list is a text file with one name in each row. I keep coming back to

```
for i in $(cat ../dir/file); do cp binaryfile.docx "$i_binaryfile.docx"; done
```

There is no error.  Only one file titled _binaryfile.docx is created.

I have looked at this [[Copy-a-file-to-a-destination-with-different-names]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291065/duplicate-file-x-times-in-command-shell)
and [[duplicate-file-x-times-in-command-shell]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291065/duplicate-file-x-times-in-command-shell) but I cannot see how they are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
for i in $(cat file); do cp binaryfile.docx "${i}_binaryfile.docx"; done
```

**EDIT:**

You can reproduce it with this example:

```
$ i=1
$ echo $i
1
$ echo $i_7

$ echo ${i}_7
1_7
```

The point is that `_` (*underscore*) character is allowed in variable
name. You can read about it in `man bash` but keep in mind that it's
written in a very technical, succinct language:

```
   name   A  word  consisting  only  of alphanumeric characters and underscores, and
          beginning with an alphabetic character or an underscore.  Also referred to
          as an identifier.
```

And later on:

```
A variable is a parameter denoted by a name.
```

And:

```
   ${parameter}
          The value of parameter is  substituted.   The  braces  are  required  when
          parameter  is  a  positional  parameter  with more than one digit, or when
          parameter is followed by a character which is not  to  be  interpreted  as
          part  of  its name.  The parameter is a shell parameter as described above
          PARAMETERS) or an array reference (Arrays).
```

So if we have a variable named `i` and we want to print its
value next to adjacent `_` we have to enclose it in `{}` to tell
`Bash` that the name of the variable ends before `_`.

Comment: Can you please explain the answer?

Comment: @Debian_yadav: I updated my answer.

Comment: As noted by RoVo this technique is best being avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues in your command:

The first has already been described by @Arkadiusz Drabczyk answer:

The underscore is a valid character for variable names, so your variable name doesn't stop after `$i`. You should use `${i}`.

---

The second issue: You should not loop over lines of a file using `for line in $(cat file); ...`. While this might work for you in this case, it is generally very bad practice, as it will split words, not lines.

Better to use something else, e.g.

```
xargs -a file -I{} cp binaryfile.docx "{}_binaryfile.docx"
```

or

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
    cp binaryfile.docx "${i}_binaryfile.docx"
done < file
```

Comment: Avoid processing text with `while..read`. You can do this easily and safely if you read the filenames into an array then iterate over the elements and run `cp source element`.